# unable to use Wifi on my Dell Vostro 1400 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

How do I enable wifi with Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Vostro 1400 .
Yesterday I tried some commands as you have suggested previously to other users . but today i am facing the same problem. Wireless networking is not highlighted. output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` is

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0227]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please add some more information about the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have reinstall ubuntu 12.04. Now I can use LAN without any problem.

Comment: Can you add the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` to your question

Comment: I don't know the main issue ... may be drivers need to be install.. # When i checked about the network Only LAN is highlighted. but wireless network button is not highlighted. I have already click the button enable wireless.  but no idea more to ---- how to install wifi drivers.

Comment: the result of the above command is

Comment: 09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0227]
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: 09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0227]
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` and reboot should fix it unless the firmware-b43-lpphy-installer package is no longer available then `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot